# How can only allow 1 accordion to open up at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have **[4 accordions](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/nj1z1d9z/show/)** <-- click here to see

- Right now all of them will open up when I click on **" View Report "**
- Those btns have a `class=".sa-hide-btn-[a,b,c,d]"`
- My accordion body has an `id="sa-collapse-[a,b,c,d]"`
- When I clicked on them, I notice a class `in` is toggle on my `id="sa-collapse-[a,b,c,d]"`

---

## My goal

is to tweak my JS and only allow **1** accordion to open up at a time.

- which mean if any of the btn is clicked :
- I should take off class **`in`** from the rest of the accordion and added to only the one that is clicked.

right ? Is my seem logic correct ?

---

## With that in mind - I come up with

```
 var lists = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ];

    lists.forEach(function(list) {

      $(".sa-report-btn-" + list).click(function () {

        $("#sa-collapse-" + list).removeClass("in");

        $(".sa-hide-" + list).removeClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-" + list).addClass("hidden");



      });

      $(".sa-hide-btn-" + list).click(function () {

        $("#sa-collapse-" + list).addClass("in");

        $(".sa-hide-" + list).addClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-" + list).removeClass("hidden");
      
      });
```

---

## Result

All my accordion still opened up every time I click on them.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bheng/nj1z1d9z/)

Can someone please tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing this

```
var lists = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ];

      lists.forEach(function(list) {

      $(".sa-report-btn-" + list).click(function () {

        $("*[class^='sa-report-']").removeClass("hidden");
        $("*[class^='sa-hide-']").addClass("hidden");


        $(".sa-hide-" + list).removeClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-" + list).addClass("hidden");

        $(".panel-collapse").removeClass("in");
        $("#sa-collapse-" + list).find( $(".panel-collapse") ).addClass("in");

      });



      $(".sa-hide-btn-" + list).click(function () {

        $(".sa-hide-" + list).addClass("hidden");
        $(".sa-report-" + list).removeClass("hidden");

      });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a variable named lists but below, you used list, maybe it's the problem?

Comment: I used for each loop, so I don't think that is the problem.